# Can I map resources to a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, routes

I have my resources already defined, but a client wants to change the names of the URLs to match their brand (e.g. something like "catalog" when the resource is currently "products").  Can I specify a different controller name with a resource so I can get all the built-in resources functionality without having to actually rename the controller and model names?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For the record: `map.resources :products, :controller => "catalog"` is how you do this.

Comment: How could you do this in rails 3

Comment: Same way, but without the `map.`

Comment: See also the path: parameters, which works for me without breaking url for (e.g. if you later ask for url_for(@product) it breaks). Sorry, not sure of the terminology / rationale but that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The [rails guide specifies how to use specific controllers for certain routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use).

You can do something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products, controller: "catalog"       
end
```

#### Conventions

```
# but rails conventions suggests you should pluralise your controller name
# so use "catalogs" (plural) instead of the singular "catalog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like it's as simple as adding the controller name, and it seems to be working.  Nevermind!